# Vue-router doesn't seem to load the default route on page load

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I set up my Vue 2.0 project with `vue-router` and `vue-cli`. Each page in my project is a separate `.vue` component wired together by routes.

This is my `router/index.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Login from '@/components/Login/Login'
import Component1 from '@/components/Component1/Component1'
import Component2 from '@/components/component2/component2'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  history : false,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path : '/component1',
      name : 'Component1',
      component : Component1
    },
    {
      path : '/component2',
      name : 'Component2',
      component : Component2
    },
    {
      path : '*',
      redirect : '/'
    }
  ]
});
```

When I run my project with `npm run dev` command, it loads the login page as intended, in URL `localhost:8080/#/`.

**Problem:**

After I type in my user name and password in the login page, the app redirects me to the same login page with URL `localhost:8080/?#/`. Notice the question mark before the hash. At this point I am forced to type in my username and password once more, so that it routes me to the correct URL (in this case `localhost:8080/?#/component1` etc).

When I go to the URL directly  `localhost:8080/?#/`, then this problem does not occur. How do I solve this problem? I don't want users to type in their credentials twice.

Comment: Is your login form submitting as a GET instead of a POST or XHR request?  See here: https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/4801/vue-router-vuex-question-mark-before-hashbang-and-page-reload

Comment: I'm not using vuex. I'm using a POST request for login. 

Also, the login page reloads no matter what the credentials are. Even simply clicking on login button does the same.

Comment: vuex was irrelevant to that question I linked, but I may have been on the wrong track if you're certain you're using POST throughout.

Comment: Although based on your answer, your form was indeed submitting as a GET.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself after seeing Daniel's comment by replacing the `<form>` with `<div>` in my login page.